# Word wrap that preserves indent from previous line

Tags: indentation, wrapping

*This may really be a basic emacs lisp question, but I'm just starting to learn some Clojure -- tiptoeing along the first steps of the newbie's path -- and don't know any elisp yet.*

**How can one set Word Wrap mode to indent to the first character of the previous line?**

Word-wrap visual line mode mode is good, but the indents are lost on wrap, making it harder to scan code by eye.

Ideally I'd want to indent up to a point, say, 30 characters max for example, to avoid overdoing it...

I'm guessing that to get this programmatically I'd need a conditional elisp statement in my emacs file.

It seems many people would have done this. Or is there a reason not to? How can it be implemented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`word-wrap` is pretty special variable as it's a variable that controls how Emacs' display engine operates when showing a buffer in a window.  It is accompanied by `wrap-prefix` which allows you to prepend space to a wrapped line for the entire buffer:

```
(setq word-wrap t)
(setq wrap-prefix (make-string 30 ?\s))
```

There is no convenient setting for the behaviour you've described to.  It could probably be implemented in the form of a minor mode that adds the `wrap-prefix` text property with the desired value to each line after examining the indentation of the previous line though.

Comment: I see, thanks very much. I guess it'll have to wait...

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled across an answer to this... [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559061/emacs-how-to-keep-the-indentation-level-of-a-very-long-wrapped-line)...

You can use the package [Adaptive-Wrap](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/adaptive-wrap-0.4.el).

It's pretty nice, there's an "extra indent" option you can use for the wrapped line, though no max indent (but seems like it could be added with just a line or two of code).

The author of the Stack Overflow post, [Francesco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225607/francesco), gives us the basic commands, and adds the snippet below to his `init.el` file. I tried adding it to my `.emacs` file. So far so good! At least in JavaScript and Clojure.

> After having installed the package, just run the following commands:
>
> - `M-x visual-line-mode RET` (to wrap long lines)
> - `M-x adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode RET` (to make wrapped lines indent nicely)

```
(when (fboundp 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
  (defun my-activate-adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode ()
    "Toggle `visual-line-mode' and `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode' simultaneously."
    (adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode (if visual-line-mode 1 -1)))
  (add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook 'my-activate-adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode))
```

There is more about it, comments etc., at [the original post on Stack Overflow from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559061/emacs-how-to-keep-the-indentation-level-of-a-very-long-wrapped-line).

Comment: Ah, so that's what it's for. Thanks, didn't know that.